# Review audit suggests "voting to close" an answer

Tags: bug, review, review-audit, low-quality-posts

[image]

Just passed a review audit. It suggested I "vote to close" an answer.

Please fix this -- making the message dependent on the Q/A bit of a reviewed post should work.

Comment: Better fix: turn off audits.

Comment: no i think the audits are a good thing, (atleast it can capture some allow everything reviewers)